# Is it possible to add inline css styling to a twig email template?

Tags: theming, webforms

Is it possible to add inline css styling to a twig email template? Not as a source file reference but by inclusion of css within the template similar to html `<style>...</style>`functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML emails, you have to use the inline style attribute.

The [Mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module might be able to inline your external CSS.